# weak-modules from module-init tools directory

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I see in `module-init` directory, files named as `weak-modules*`.

```
bash # ls /usr/lib/module-init-tools/weak-modules*
/usr/lib/module-init-tools/weak-modules  /usr/lib/module-init-tools/weak-modules2
```

What exactly it is? and when it is used?
I think it is used while initializing the modules, as it is present in `module-init` directory.

Answer (score 6):

The `weak-modules` script determines which modules are kABI compatible with installed kernels and sets up symlinks in `/lib/modules/$KERNELRELEASE/weak-updates` so that compatible modules can be used by kernels other than the one it was compiled against.

It  is used when installing a module so that links are made in the the `weak-updates` directory for all installed kernels. It is also used when new kernels are installed so that it's `weak-updates` directory is populated by compatible modules installed on the system under other kernels.

Comment: This is a rather short but accurate answer! Should be marked as valid answer!